# Way to make an actual copy of the values of list to another in DART

Tags: dart

After researching, I understand that when a list is set with values from another list, only the references are copied - not the actual values.

Initially, I want to create a list with the exact copy of the values of the original list. Then, after performing some operations to the original list, I wan to be able to copy the values from the copy list back to the original one.

I couldn't find a solution so far which doesn't set the values in the copy list to be the same as the new values in the original list.

The code below shows the logic of what I want to execute but couldn't find the right "function" to be able to create a "clone" a list.

```
class NumPairs {
  NumPairs({this.first, this.second});
  int first;
  int second;
}

main() {
  List<NumPairs> from = [
    NumPairs(
      first: 1,
      second: 2,
    ),
    NumPairs(
      first: 2,
      second: 1,
    ),
  ];

  List<NumPairs> to = [];

  to = from;

  print('${to[0].first} ' + '${to[0].second} ' + ' inital TO');
  print('${from[0].first} ' + '${from[0].second} ' + ' inital FROM');

  to[0].first = 0;
  to[0].second = 0;

  print('${to[0].first} ' + '${to[0].second} ' + ' after zeroed TO = 0');
  print(
      '${from[0].first} ' + '${from[0].second} ' + ' FROM after TO is zeroed');

  to = from;

  print('${to[0].first} ' +
      '${to[0].second} ' +
      ' after trying to copy to from FROM');
}
```

Output:

```
1 2  inital TO
1 2  inital FROM
0 0  after zeroed TO = 0
0 0  FROM after TO is zeroed
0 0  after trying to copy to from FROM
```

Comment: I am not sure what behavior you want. Can you write what output you want? If you want to "clone" you can just create a new list from your existing list. If you want a new list where each element is a copy from elements inside another list you can use the map method to traverse the old list and copy each element. But I am not sure what you are looking for so I cannot make an detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to be able to clone objects in the original list.  This can be done as follows.

```
class NumPairs {
    NumPairs({this.first, this.second});
    int first;
    int second;
    NumPairs.clone(NumPairs numpairs): this(first: numpairs.first, second: numpairs.second);
}
```

Where the named constructor 'clone' was added.

Now you can clone the original list using:

```
List<NumPairs> to = from.map((elem)=>NumPairs.clone(elem)).toList();
```

The original code becomes the following.

```
class NumPairs {
  NumPairs({this.first, this.second});
  int first;
  int second;
  NumPairs.clone(NumPairs numpairs): this(first: numpairs.first, second: numpairs.second);
}

main() {
  List<NumPairs> from = [
    NumPairs(
      first: 1,
      second: 2,
    ),
    NumPairs(
      first: 2,
      second: 1,
    ),
  ];

  //to = from;
  // Gets replaced with the following which clones the 'from' list
  List<NumPairs> to = from.map((elem)=>NumPairs.clone(elem)).toList();


  print('${to[0].first} ' + '${to[0].second} ' + ' inital TO');
  print('${from[0].first} ' + '${from[0].second} ' + ' inital FROM');

  to[0].first = 0;
  to[0].second = 0;

  print('${to[0].first} ' + '${to[0].second} ' + ' after zeroed TO = 0');
  print(
      '${from[0].first} ' + '${from[0].second} ' + ' FROM after TO is zeroed');

  to = from;

  print('${to[0].first} ' +
      '${to[0].second} ' +
      ' after trying to copy to from FROM');
}
```

Result

```
1 2  inital TO
1 2  inital FROM
0 0  after zeroed TO = 0
1 2  FROM after TO is zeroed
1 2  after trying to copy to from FROM
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks! I found some similar solutions before posting the question but I wasn't able to figure out this part of the code: from.map((elem)=>NumPairs.clone(elem)).toList();